# Export db object in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I really can't understand. let's say I have conneced to my mongodb

```
let db;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api/todos', todosRoutes); // routes in separate file

MongoClient.connect(
  uri, 
  {useNewUrlParser: true}, 
  (err, client) => {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
    db = client.db('todosApp');
    module.exports = db; // how can I export this db so my routes can use it?
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
    })
  }
)
```

In my routes

```
const db = require('../app').db;
const collectionName = 'todos';

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection(collectionName)
    .find()
    .toArray()
    .then(collection => res.json(collection))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err))
})
```

I always get an error that db is undefined, which I can understand, but can't get how to handle it then?

Comment: Have you tried using const require('../app'); without .db? Because you are assigning db directly to module.exports, that means require will return only the db object. That means require().db is undefined tho.

Answer (score 1):

You `require()`d that file and got the value of `require('../app').db` synchronously, before `app` set `exports.db`.

You should only access `.db` later, once it actually exists.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I should do it after my connect statement?